# How to show a child form within a mdi container form which its windowstate= maximized?

Tags: c#, winforms, childwindow, mdiparent

How can I show a child form within a mdi container form which its windowstate= maximized ?

when I put these below lines of code when my child form is loading (by clicking on a menu Item of my Main form), the child form loses its parent position and does not show within its parent form.

```
private void mnuUnit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frmUnit frm = new frmUnit();
    frm.MdiParent = this;
    frm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    frm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Did you forget to paste your code?

To show an MDI child form as maximized, you do the following:

```
// This is a method on the MDI parent (IsMdiContainer = true)
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myForm = new MyCustomForm();
    myForm.MdiParent = this;
    myForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
    myForm.Show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the dock style to fill and before calling show, use

```
myForm.BringToFront();
```