# How can manage border less child form with border less MDI form in c#?

Tags: c#

I have custom windows form that has no border.I apply that custom form on child form. And I have custom MDIParent Form that has also no border. So, My problem is when I maximise child form then top border of is appear out side of MDIForm so how can manage or solve this issue using c#.[See my snapshot for more detail of my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLB9A.png) I want to remove border with maximise button from top of the custom MDIForm.

Answer (score -1):

I am unsure how you are calling the child Form, but here is an example:

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myForm = new MyCustomForm();
    myForm.MdiParent = this;
    myForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None; //this should hide the border even when it is maximized.
    myForm.Show();
}
```

OR, you can capture the 'maximize' event and override it with your own method which once again makes sure there is no border:

```
private void MaximizeWindow() 
{
    var rectangle = Screen.FromControl(this).Bounds;
    this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
    Size = new Size(rectangle.Width, rectangle.Height);
    Location = new Point(0, 0);
    Rectangle workingRectangle = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
    this.Size = new Size(workingRectangle.Width, workingRectangle.Height);
}
```

and to capture the maximize event:

```
private void Form1_Resize (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Form1.WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        // Do some stuff
    }
}
```

Sources:

-[How to show a child form within a mdi container form which its windowstate= maximized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2356337/how-to-show-a-child-form-within-a-mdi-container-form-which-its-windowstate-maxi)

-[Remove the title bar in Windows Forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7482922/remove-the-title-bar-in-windows-forms)

Comment: May I ask how you eliminated the borders for the child element? What method did you use, some code snippets would be nice to go on.

Comment: Yes why not, I use this code                                          this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is: `this.ControlBox = false;`. Otherwise in the worst case, you can disable maximizing and set a fixed size for your child form.